# C# : Anytype Deserialization Error

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I'm very new to C#. I'm trying to consume data from web service using proxy classes generated by VS2015. Below is the snippet of XSD where the error occurs.

XSD snippet below

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PriceList">
 <s:complexType>
  <s:sequence>
   <s:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="http://www/w3/org/2001/XMLSchema" processContents="lax"/>
   <s:any minOccurs="1" namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" processContents="lax"/>
   </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

I inspected the response using fiddler and it appears the dataset has `xs:anyType` for one of the element and that is where i get the exception.

Exception: Column requires a valid DataType.

I have searched a lot of forums and couldn't get answer on how to handle this. Sorry if i overlooked and this problem was already answered. I cannot change the way the response is coming.

Can someone help me to get away from this error?

Comment: You need a namespace defined for 'any' which is declared on xml posted.

Comment: It has namespace, I couldn't figure out why. I'm moving away and writing my own sevice. Thanks .

Comment: You need to find out where the namespace is defined in the xsd.   It could be inside another namespace on the web.